# Underline at the same level

Tags: vertical-alignment, fontsize, text-decorations

I want to underline alpha's and beta's, but at the same level. I mean, I don't want [image]
 but [image]. Maybe there is already a command that make it but I couldn't find it. The second image was obtained with the following command :

```
$\newlength{\espa}
\settowidth{\espa}{$\alpha$}\rlap{\underline{\hspace{\espa}}}\alpha,
\settowidth{\espa}{$\beta$}\rlap{\underline{\hspace{\espa}}}\beta$
```

which is hardly working but not totally. In normal math mode, no pbm. In scriptsize (or tiny or anything else) math mode, no pbm. But if I am in math mode within an exponent, then the `\settowidth` command does not seem to take into account that I am in sciptsize mode and, as a matter of fact, the underline is too long (*e.g.* [image]).

Any idea ?

Comment: Would incorporating a `\strut` help to put all underlines at the same level?

Comment: A `\mathstrut` would be more appropriate, assuming math mode is where you want to do it. It will scale with (sub)subscripts, which the regular `\strut` won't do.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$\underline{\smash{\beta}}$
```

will do the trick.

Comment: Excellent! I have one question though: how can I achieve that the line of `\underline{mytext}` has the same width as `mytext`?

Comment: @Leon: You mean it doesn't?

Comment: Yes, in my case, the line of `\emph{\underline{\smash{Proof}}}:` is shorter than the word `Proof.` I was hoping there was some option to set the additional width manually, like `\underline[2pt]{...}` or something like that...

Comment: @Leon: Ah. Unrelated to this question, really. But what you need is an italic correction: `\emph{\underline{\smash{Proof\/}}}:`. Or better yet, restructure your usage to allow `\emph` to do its job of adding italic correction automagically: `\underline{\emph{Proof}}:`.